# (solved)I cannot use enter key in the console in PyCharm 2021.1.3 debug mode

Tags: python, pycharm

When I am debugging, I like to drag the `console` window out of the `PyCharm` main program to form a separate window, but recently discovered a problem, I can not use the `enter` key in the debug mode console, when I finish typing the python statement and press enter, similar For the effect of `shift +  return`, a line is added, so that the statement cannot be executed.

If I do not drag the `console` window out to form a separate window, the `enter` key is used normally. What is the reason for this?

I reinstalled `PyCharm` 2021.1.3 and it didn't work.

---

I reinstalled `PyCharm` 2020.3.5 (Community Edition), and the Enter key is `normal`.

My `PyCharm` version:

```
PyCharm 2021.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-211.7628.24, built on June 30, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.60 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 40
Registry: debugger.watches.in.variables=false
```

operating system:

```
Microsoft Windows 10.0.19042.1110 Professional Edition
```

Comment: you should send it to authors of PyCharm - it is problem for them

Comment: @furas Yes, I have sent it to PyCharm's support and community

Comment: Sounds like this bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49527

Comment: @PavelKarateev Yes. Same as his .